# Woocommerce custom bulk action on products list page

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, woocommerce

I would like to add a bulk action on the Woocommerce product list page. I understand I can do this from the functions.php file on my child theme using an add filter `bulk_actions_<screen>` however I am not sure what screen the Woocommerce product list page is. I have tried several combinations and tried finding information on Google however I was unable to identify anything useful.

Thanks,
Prem

Comment: https://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/how-to-get-the-wordpress-screen-id-of-a-page explains how you can easily find out.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you so much! That worked like magic. The screen i was looking for is edit-product!